# adding notes to a 3D matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I would like to add some notes to a 3D matrix. The matrix is built thanks to the following LaTeX code and it is shown in the picture, the notes I would like to add are marked in red (something similar and not exactly the same as my red marks would also be ok).

Is there any latex code to add the notes that I have manually entered in red?

Thank you

Lello

```
        \documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

        \begin{document}


        \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=1.4cm,minimum height=7mm}]
        \matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
        {
            i(W,X_1,Y_3)  &  \cdots & i(W,X_k,Y_3) \\
            i(W_2, X_1,Y_3) &  \cdots & i(W_2,X_k,Y_3) \\
            \vdots          &  \ddots & \vdots         \\
            i(W_j,X_1,Y_3)  &  \cdots & i(W_j,X_k,Y_3) \\
        };
        \matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(4.9,1.65)$)
        {
            i(W,X_1,Y_2)  &  \cdots & i(W,X_k,Y_2) \\
            i(W_2, X_1,Y_2) &  \cdots & i(W_2,X_k,Y_2) \\
            \vdots          &  \ddots & \vdots         \\
            i(W_j,X_1,Y_2)  &  \cdots & i(W_j,X_k,Y_2) \\
        };
        \matrix (mC) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mB.south west)+(4.9,1.65)$)
        {
            i(W,X_1,Y_1)  &  \cdots & i(W,X_k,Y_1) \\
            i(W_2, X_1,Y_1) &  \cdots & i(W_2,X_k,Y_1) \\
            \vdots          &  \ddots & \vdots         \\
            i(W_j,X_1,Y_1)  &  \cdots & i(W_j,X_k,Y_1) \\
        };
        \draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mC.north east);
        \draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mC.north west);
        \draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mC.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}%


        \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure there are better `tikz` ways, but I decided to have fun with `\stackinset` and `\slantbox` to achieve the effect.

```
        \documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
        \usepackage{tikz,stackengine,mathtools}
        \usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][\slantvalue]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
        \begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=1.4cm,minimum height=7mm}]
        \matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
        {
            i(W,X_1,Y_3)  &  \cdots & i(W,X_k,Y_3) \\
            i(W_2, X_1,Y_3) &  \cdots & i(W_2,X_k,Y_3) \\
            \vdots          &  \ddots & \vdots         \\
            i(W_j,X_1,Y_3)  &  \cdots & i(W_j,X_k,Y_3) \\
        };
        \matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(4.9,1.65)$)
        {
            i(W,X_1,Y_2)  &  \cdots & i(W,X_k,Y_2) \\
            i(W_2, X_1,Y_2) &  \cdots & i(W_2,X_k,Y_2) \\
            \vdots          &  \ddots & \vdots         \\
            i(W_j,X_1,Y_2)  &  \cdots & i(W_j,X_k,Y_2) \\
        };
        \matrix (mC) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mB.south west)+(4.9,1.65)$)
        {
            i(W,X_1,Y_1)  &  \cdots & i(W,X_k,Y_1) \\
            i(W_2, X_1,Y_1) &  \cdots & i(W_2,X_k,Y_1) \\
            \vdots          &  \ddots & \vdots         \\
            i(W_j,X_1,Y_1)  &  \cdots & i(W_j,X_k,Y_1) \\
        };
        \draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mC.north east);
        \draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mC.north west);
        \draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mC.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\kern10pt%
\stackinset{r}{20pt}{b}{8pt}{\rotatebox{-130}{\slantbox[-.81]{$\mid\!\xleftrightarrow{~~~~~\rotatebox{180}{$\Delta y$}~~~~~}\!\mid$}}}{%
\stackinset{l}{-21pt}{b}{67pt}{\rotatebox{90}{$\mid\!\xleftrightarrow{~~~\rotatebox{-90}{$\Delta w$}~~~}\!\mid$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-35pt}{b}{-18pt}{$\mid\!\xleftrightarrow{\textstyle~~~\Delta x~~~}\!\mid$}{%
  \copy0
}}}

        \end{document}
```

[image]